# Enable/Disable a button in Xcode 8

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a stopwatch and I need to disable the stop button until an elapsed time or greater, I have it working but if I were to click the stop button before the elapsed time (which nothing happens)then click it when the time has elapsed it does not work.  If I start the the timer and wait for or let it pass if > 10 seconds it works fine

```
@IBAction func firstHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if startStopWatch == true {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(StopWatchVC.updateStopwatch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startStopWatch = false
            self.firstHalf.alpha = 0.2
            self.secondHalf.alpha = 0.2
            self.endFirstHalf.alpha = 0.2
            self.endSecondHalf.alpha = 0.2
            seconds = 0
            minutes = 0
            tempTimelineLbl.text = "Kick Off here at "
        }
    }

    @IBAction func endFirstHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if seconds < 10 {
            endFirstHalf.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            if startStopWatch == false && seconds > 10 {
                endFirstHalf.isEnabled = true
                timer.invalidate()
                startStopWatch = true
                seconds = 0
                minutes = 45
                stopwatchLabel.text = "45:00"
                tempTimelineLbl.text = "Half Time"
                self.secondHalf.alpha = 1
                self.firstHalf.alpha = 0.2
                self.endFirstHalf.alpha = 0.2

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are deciding if the button should be enabled or not *after* the user taps it. As a result when you tap the stop button before 10 seconds have passed the button gets disabled meaning it can't be tapped again as there is nothing to tell the button to be enabled again.

Your `firstHalfClicked` method should disable the stop button. Your `updateStopwatch` method should enable the button once 10 seconds (or whatever interval you want) have passed. `endFirstHalfClicked` should only have the code from within the `else` block in it minus the line that enables `endFirstHalf`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense